# If $T: V\rightarrow W$ is isomorphic then $T$ is invertible. Prove that its inverse is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Ok so I know $T$ is a linear transformation so it stands that this is true:

$T(\alpha x + y) = \alpha T(x) + T(y)$

However, I'm a little lost on how I should use this information to prove that the inverse is also a linear transformation.

Comment: 2 people think that this question is well researched

Comment: @AlecTeal I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The question, as it stands, makes no sense to me. I think you mean: "I'm trying to show that if $T : V \rightarrow W$ is a linear transform that is bijective, then the function $T^{-1}$ is linear."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T: V \to W$ is an isomorphism, then for any $w_1, w_2 \in W$ there exist unique $v_1, v_2 \in V$ with

$$w_1 = T(v_1) \quad\text{and}\quad w_2 = T(v_2).$$

(Why do they exist, and why are the unique?)

Now, can you show $T^{-1}(\alpha w_1 + \beta w_2) = \alpha T^{-1}(w_1) + \beta T^{-1}(w_2)$, using only the linearity of $T$? (Remember, $v_1 = T^{-1}(w_1)$, similarly for $v_2$).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that T is invertible so we have $T = (T^{-1})^{-1}$ I will denote $T^{-1} = M$ just for clarification. Note that $TT^{-1} = I$

So since $T = M^{-1}$ $M(x + y) = M(T(M(x)) + T(M(y))$ now Since T is 
linear transformation we have $M(T(M(x)) + T(M(y))) = M(T(M(x) + M(y)))$
Now since M and T are inverse with each other they will cancel to identity
and we will have $M(T(M(x) + M(y))) = M(x) + M(y)$

so we have $T^{-1}(x + b) = M(x + y) = M(x) + M(y) = T^{-1}(x) + T^{-1}(y)$
and you are done for the sake of completeness here is also the second property of linear transformation.

$T^{-1}(ax) = T^{-1}(aT(T^{-1}(x))) = T^{-1}(T(aT^{-1}(x))) = T^{-1}(aTT^{-1}(x)) = aT^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: You should be more careful and separate your ideas with punctuation like commas and periods.  For example, in the beginning of your second paragraph, you say "So since $T = M^{-1}$ $M(x + y) = \dots$".  To the untrained eye, it could look like you are saying $T$ equals $M^{-1}M(x + y)$.  It would have been better to write "So since $T = M^{-1}$, $M(x + y) = \dots$".

Comment: Yes, I agree my latex writing skills isn't that good.